# spring-kafka-3.0.9.module - can't find/download file

Tags: spring-kafka

is there any problem with downloading file spring-kafka-3.0.9.module?
File doesn't exists and it ruins my local build at bamboo machine.

tried to download from my local repo (nexus) but file dissapeared i can't download from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/3.0.9/

Answer (score 0):

Gradle `.module` file are available there since version `3.0.10`. Consider to upgrade to the latest one: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/3.0.11/